# How to Match Json with string using Javascript

Tags: jquery, regex, json

What I need to do:

- I need to match Json with `string`.

case 1: When industry data is set in Json

```
        ["", "app.php", "automotive", "tradeshows"]
```

JQuery code:

```
  $( document ).ready(function() 
 {


    var match =  window.location.pathname.split("/");
    console.log(match[3]);

    if(match[3]=="conferences")
    {
         console.log("true");
    $('#radio3').prop('checked', true);

    }
    else if(match[3]=="tradeshows")
    {
        console.log("afeef");
        $('#radio2').prop('checked', true);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#radio1').prop('checked', true);
    }



   });
```

case 2: When industry data is not set in Json

```
     ["", "app.php",  "tradeshows"]
```

- In this case match would be failed.
- Is there any other way in match Json with `string` in JQuery?
- I need to match the Json with `string` so is there any other way so that I could match Json with `string`?

Comment: Looks like you just want to match JSON attribute value against the string value and not the entire JSON object, am I right?

Comment: You could use: `var match =  window.location.pathname.split("/"); if(match.length < 4) {$('#radio1').prop('checked', true); return;} //rest of code...`. But FYI, this has nothing to do with JSON but javascript array, JSON is an object notation

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `indexOf()` to detect if `automotive` is available or not. See the below code

```js
function myFunction(page) {
    var pages = ["", "app.php", "automotive", "tradeshows"];
    var a = pages.indexOf(page);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the button to display the position of the element "tradeshows":</p>

<button onclick="myFunction('automotive')">Check for automotive</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('automotive1')">Check for automotive1</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

**Note:** *The indexOf method was introduced in JavaScript 1.6, and does not work in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.*

Comment: How is it relevant to the question?